# How is it possible to call php artisan doctrine:schema:update before the testing starts? PhpUnit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I would like to test my project using PHPUnit. My project is built on Laravel and Doctrine. For testing I use an sqlite `:memory:` database. Since it is a memory database, I can not generate the tables from my entities before testing, and I have to call `php artisan doctrine:schema:update` when `phpunit`starts.

I tried to add the `RefreshDatabase` trait to the class, but it still does not work:

```
namespace Tests\Unit\Example;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

use EntityManager;

class MyExampleTest extends TestCase
{

    use RefreshDatabase;

    // ...

}
```

I get this error:

```
General error: 1 no such table: users
```

Comment: Use `setUp` method in test class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your migrations before each test you can use the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase` trait, this will set up the database tables from your migrations and clean everything before running the test.

so to use it include the class and add the `use RefreshDatabase` to your test class.

here is a link to the docs.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test

Comment: I did that, but I get this error: `General error: 1 no such table: users`

Comment: The users migration is probably the first one to run when you run your migration, so maybe also check you migrations and connection to de DB